# Check whether a list starts with the elements of another list and if found return both the values together

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pattern-matching, startswith

I have 2 lists:

```
substance = ['HYDROCHLORIC ACID 2M', 'ROPIVACAINE HYDROCHLORIDE MONOHYDRATE', 'SODIUM CHLORIDE', 'SODIUM HYDROXIDE 2M', 'WATER FOR INJECTIONS']

extracteddata = ['Ropivacaine hydrochloride monohydrate for injection (corresponding to 2 mg Ropivacaine hydrochloride anhydrous) 2.12 mg Active ingredient Ph Eur ', 'Sodium chloride for injection 8.6 mg Tonicity contributor Ph Eur ', 'Sodium hydroxide 2M q.s. pH-regulator Ph Eur, NF Hydrochloric acid 2M q.s. pH-regulator Ph Eur, NF ', 'Water for Injections to 1 ml Solvent Ph Eur, USP The product is filled into polypropylene bags sealed with rubber stoppers and aluminium caps with flip-off seals. The primary container is enclosed in a blister. 1(1)']
```

I want to check which element of extracteddata starts with which element of substance and return them together.

Expected output:

```
matchedlist = [substance:'ROPIVACAINE HYDROCHLORIDE MONOHYDRATE',extracteddata:'Ropivacaine hydrochloride monohydrate for injection (corresponding to 2 mg Ropivacaine hydrochloride anhydrous) 2.12 mg Active ingredient Ph Eur'],[substance:'SODIUM HYDROXIDE 2M', extracteddata:'Sodium hydroxide 2M q.s. pH-regulator Ph Eur, NF Hydrochloric acid 2M q.s. pH-regulator Ph Eur, NF ']
```

and likewise...

Anyhelp regarding this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a possible solution:

```
result = []
for s in substance:
    for e in extracteddata:
        if e.upper().startswith(s.upper()):
            result.append([s, e])
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
substance = ['HYDROCHLORIC ACID 2M', 'ROPIVACAINE HYDROCHLORIDE MONOHYDRATE', 'SODIUM CHLORIDE', 'SODIUM HYDROXIDE 2M', 'WATER FOR INJECTIONS']

extracteddata = ['Ropivacaine hydrochloride monohydrate for injection (corresponding to 2 mg Ropivacaine hydrochloride anhydrous) 2.12 mg Active ingredient Ph Eur ', 'Sodium chloride for injection 8.6 mg Tonicity contributor Ph Eur ', 'Sodium hydroxide 2M q.s. pH-regulator Ph Eur, NF Hydrochloric acid 2M q.s. pH-regulator Ph Eur, NF ', 'Water for Injections to 1 ml Solvent Ph Eur, USP The product is filled into polypropylene bags sealed with rubber stoppers and aluminium caps with flip-off seals. The primary container is enclosed in a blister. 1(1)']

json_data = []
for data in substance:
    for data1 in extracteddata:
        if data1.lower().startswith(data.lower()):
            json_data.append({"substance":data,"extracteddata:":data1})
print(json_data)
```

Hope it might works:)